# How to display a navigation bar in Lyx?

Tags: lyx

In LyX, is there a way to display sections/subsections, etc. of a document next to the window with the content of the document? In other words, I would want to see  a navigation bar next to the main window of the document without going to the *Navigate* menu. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1: <kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>Outline Pane</kbd>

Result:

[image: mwe]

Method 2: <kbd>Insert</kbd> > <kbd>List/TOC</kbd> > <kbd>Table of contents</kbd> > Click on the `Table of contents` gray box

Result:

Mostly the same, but obviously now the document will print the table of contents where the gray box was inserted.